# Comparing lists elements to sublist elements in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

**df**

```
col1                       col2
['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']   [['ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh'], ['qq', 'ww', 'ee', 'rr']]
['ss', 'dd', 'ff', 'gg']   [['mm', 'nn', 'vv', 'cc'], ['zz', 'aa', 'jj', 'kk']]
['ss', 'dd']               [['mm', 'nn', 'vv', 'cc'], ['zz', 'aa', 'jj', 'kk']]
```

I'd like to be able to run a function that concats the first list element in `col1` to the first sublist **elements** (there are multiple sublists) in `col2`, then concats the second list element in `col1` to the second sublist elements in `col2`.

**Results would be like this column:**

```
results
[['aaee', 'bbff', 'ccgg', 'ddhh'],['aaqq', 'bbww', 'ccee', 'ddrr']]
[['ssmm', 'ddnn', 'ffvv', 'ggcc'],['sszz', 'ddaa', 'ffjj', 'ggkk']]
[['ssmm', 'ddnn'],['sszz', 'ddaa']]
```

I'm thinking it would have something to do with looping through the first elements in `col1` and somehow loop and match them to the corresponding items in each sublist in `col2` - how can I do this?

---

**Converted code**

```
[[[df1.agg(lambda x: get_top_matches(u,w), axis=1) for u,w in zip(x,v)]\
for v in y] for x,y in zip(df1['parent_org_name_list'], df1['children_org_name_sublists'])]
```

Results:
[image]

Comment: Are the list lengths going to stay constant?  That is, will the sublists in `col2` always be the same length as the list in `col1`?

Comment: @ASGM Actually no. I just checked again - in this case, the operation would stop after the number of items in the `col1` list had cycled through each element in each sublist in `col2`

Comment: What if `col1` is shorter than `col2`?

Comment: for the purpose of this post, lets just stop the loop once `col1` is done. But the overall purpose would be to get all the combinations for each element in `col1` concatenated with each element in each sublist in `col2`. that's just a lot of combos to write out

Comment: The solution from Quang Hoang is the fastest solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `zip` here:

```
[[[u+w for u,w in zip(x,v)] for v in y] for x,y in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])]
```

Output:

```
[[['aaee', 'bbff', 'ccgg', 'ddhh'], ['aaqq', 'bbww', 'ccee', 'ddrr']],
 [['ssmm', 'ddnn', 'ffvv', 'ggcc'], ['sszz', 'ddaa', 'ffjj', 'ggkk']],
 [['ssmm', 'ddnn'], ['sszz', 'ddaa']]]
```

To assign back to your dataframe, you can do:

```
df['results'] = [[[u+w for u,w in zip(x,v)] for v in y] 
            for x,y in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])]
```

Comment: this is awesome. So I actually have a slightly different need than what i posted, but it's a little complicated. Here's what I turned your code into: `[[[df1.agg(lambda x: get_top_matches(u,w), axis=1) for u,w in zip(x,v)]\
for v in y] for x,y in zip(df1['col1'], df1['col2'])]`. the `get_top_matches function just creates a similarity score based on two strings. The code i pasted doesn't quite do what I need - it gets a score for each string's letter. See the picture in the post i just added

Comment: I feel like there's something slightly different I can do to make the function work on the elements in the list, rather than the characters.

Answer (score 1):

Max, try this solution with a cycle. It allows finer control over transformations, including dealing with uneven lengths (see `len_limit` in the example):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'],['ss', 'dd', 'ff', 'gg']],
                   'c2':[[['ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh'], ['qq', 'ww', 'ee', 'rr']],
                         [['mm', 'nn', 'vv', 'cc'], ['zz', 'aa', 'jj', 'kk']]],})  

df ['c3'] = 'empty'  # send string to 'c3' so it is object data type
print(df)
                 c1                                    c2     c3
0  [aa, bb, cc, dd]  [[ee, ff, gg, hh], [qq, ww, ee, rr]]  empty
1  [ss, dd, ff, gg]  [[mm, nn, vv, cc], [zz, aa, jj, kk]]  empty

for i, row  in df.iterrows():
    c3_list = []
    len_limit = len (row['c1']
    for c2_sublist in row['c2']:
        c3_list.append([j1+j2 for j1, j2 in zip(row['c1'], c2_sublist[:len_limit])])
    df.at[i, 'c3'] = c3_list
    
print (df['c3'])

0    [[aaee, bbff, ccgg, ddhh], [aaqq, bbww, ccee, ...
1    [[ssmm, ddnn, ffvv, ggcc], [sszz, ddaa, ffjj, ...
Name: c3, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["results"] = df[["col1", "col2"]].apply(lambda x: [list(map(''.join, zip(x["col1"], el))) for el in x["col2"]], axis=1)
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> df["results"]

0    [[aaee, bbff, ccgg, ddhh], [aaqq, bbww, ccee, ...
1    [[ssmm, ddnn, ffvv, ggcc], [sszz, ddaa, ffjj, ...
2                         [[ssmm, ddnn], [sszz, ddaa]]
```